# python kivy/audiostream install error

Tags: python-2.7, clang, kivy

I want to try kivy/audiostream module but I could not install it using sudo python2.7 setup.py install I am using os x 10.9.2 .

I get this error

2 warnings generated.
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -L/opt/local/lib/db46 build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/audiostream/platform/plat_mac.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/audiostream/platform/mac_ext.o -lSDL -lSDL_mixer -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/audiostream/platform/plat_mac.so
ld: library not found for -lSDL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
brew install sdl
brew install sdl_mixer
```